# SQL Join on sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables (A, B).  They each have a different column that is basically an order or a sequence number.  Table A has 'Sequence' and the values range from 0 to 5.  Table B has 'Index' and the values are 16740, 16744, 16759, 16828, 16838, and 16990.  Unfortunately I do not know the significance of these values.  But I do believe they will always match in sequential order.  I want to join these tables on these numbers where 0 = 16740, 1 = 16744, etc.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Join on UDF then that convert Sequence to Index

Comment: Create a mapping table, and join against that.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions.  Let me add a few details.  The 'Sequence' and 'Index' values are not static.  'Sequence' will always start at 0 and could be anywhere from 1 to 500 numbers.  'Index' is always a unique number, continually increasing.  It never resets like 'Sequence'.  But they are always sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values are in ascending order as per your example, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to achieve this:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Index])-1 RN
              FROM B)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get it to work using this format.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` expression to convert table a's values to table b's values (or vise-versa) and join on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.[sequence] = CASE b.[index] WHEN 16740 THEN 0 
                                          WHEN 16744 THEN 1
                                          WHEN 16759 THEN 2
                                          WHEN 16828 THEN 3
                                          WHEN 16838 THEN 4
                                          WHEN 16990 THEN 5
                                          ELSE NULL
                            END;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mureinik has a great example.  If down the road you do end up adding more numbers maybe putting this information into a new table would be a good idea.

```
CREATE TABLE C(
AInfo    INT,
BInfo    INT
)
INSERT INTO TABLE C(AInfo,BInfo) VALUES(0,16740)
INSERT INTO TABLE C(AInfo,BInfo) VALUES(1,16744)
etc
```

Then you can Join all the tables.

Comment: Both yours and Mureinik's solutions will work.  I think creating a new table is probably the better route to go, as it seems to be more or less a missing chunk of the data model, and I'm presuming if one query is being designed, more will likely follow....